# I can not start my receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I never reach BootReceiver??
In my manifest i have:

```
 <receiver android:name=".app.service.receiver.BootReceiver" android:enabled="true">            
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".app.service.Process">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".app.service.Process" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

at my BootReceiver I have:

```
package cc.com.app.service.receiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();

    serviceIntent.setAction("cc.com.service.Process");

    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
}
```

Comment: What android version are you using? If you are on 3.1+, you may want to check this: http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/05/boot-completed-regression.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you include the [RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) permission in your manifest file?

**Update:**
Found something in [What does it mean "No Launcher activity found!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801371/what-does-it-mean-no-launcher-activity-found). You should be able to define the service as MAIN and LAUNCHER, both seem to be mandatory. Didn't know that either.

Comment: I can't see anything else that could be wrong. Is it the receiver that doesn't get called or the service? Maybe try something like: Log.d("BootReceiver", "started..."); in onReceive().

Comment: nope, doesn't logout enything, doesn't go to the breakpoint which is on Log.d(..);

Comment: Why did you mark this as solved if it is not? Only a few people will take a look at an already answered question.