# android app not starting in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an eclipse on a desktop working fine but on a recent install on an old laptop with a 2.4 Ghz inter core 2 duo, I'm facing some problems.

When testing an app for android, and running the emulator, It starts but when finish loading, starts with the locked screen. Then I unlock it and it goes to home, but I cannot find where the app is, as is not in the apps menu. So i think is not loading the app?

console mesage:

```
[2011-12-11 22:13:58 - ha] ------------------------------
[2011-12-11 22:13:58 - ha] Android Launch!
[2011-12-11 22:13:58 - ha] adb is running normally.
[2011-12-11 22:13:58 - ha] No Launcher activity found!
[2011-12-11 22:13:58 - ha] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2011-12-11 22:13:58 - ha] Performing sync
[2011-12-11 22:13:58 - ha] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD '40'
[2011-12-11 22:13:58 - ha] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '40'
[2011-12-11 22:14:08 - Emulator] 2011-12-11 22:14:08.267 emulator-arm[2180:80b] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
[2011-12-11 22:14:08 - ha] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-12-11 22:14:08 - ha] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-12-11 22:15:00 - ha] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-12-11 22:15:00 - ha] Uploading ha.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-12-11 22:15:01 - ha] Installing ha.apk...
```

how to fix this please?

Comment: What are you seeing in your log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice the line

```
[2011-12-11 22:13:58 - ha] No Launcher activity found!
```

It says no activity has been given Intent-Filter to be MAIN and LAUNCHER Activity of your Application

In `AndroidManifest.xml` it should look like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".NameOfMainActivity">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

read more here:

- [What does it mean "No Launcher activity found!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801371/what-does-it-mean-no-launcher-activity-found)
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html

Answer (score 3):

Look into the manifest.xml and check if there is a launcher for your app. If there is, check your log file.