# emulator doesn't show my application

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just picked up "Beginning Android 4" by apress and in chapter 3 they have you make your first app.  I've gone through it and though a few settings don't match completely (I'm guessing because the android api has been updated since the book was written), it all runs fine.  However, the book says I should see the icon for my "Now" project/app in the main menu of apps. It's not there so I'm not sure what might be wrong.  Does anyone know if there's a trick to getting it to show up?  I'm using the eclipse editor and android plugins.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem! I was seeing this in the console:

```
No Launcher activity found!
```

You need to specify the MAIN and LAUNCHER in the the intent filter for the activity you want to start on launch! There is another stackoverflow answer [explaining the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801371/what-does-it-mean-no-launcher-activity-found).

Basically make sure your AndroidManifest.xml has the MAIN and LAUNCHER arguments specified like this:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="ExampleActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

After you create your program, right click on the project and hit Run As > Android Application; this should upload the .apk and install it on your emulator - once that is finished, it will load up.

If it doesn't load up - check what the Console has to say (It's a tab in Eclipse on the bottom) as something could have gone wrong.

Make sure you don't have any red lines in your code - that means there's an error.

Comment: I think I had the wrong build target vs. minimum sdk.  I think I may have had one set to android and the other to google api.  Once I set both of these the same then it came up in the emulator.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Apparently I spoke too soon.  I started over from scratch doing the exact same thing and now the app doesn't show up in the emulator.  I've tried this about 8 times and only once was able to get it to show up.  Is the emulator really that flaky?

Comment: It shouldn't be, I never really have issues. Are there any messages in your Console?

Comment: Nothing that seems out of place.  I also had purchased the Deitel Android for Programmers and imported their doodlz program to test it just to be sure it wasn't something I was doing wrong.  This app too isn't showing up in the emulator.  I'm guessing there must be some tool or something that didn't get installed correctly when I first installed eclipse and the sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this also works.

1. In Eclipse ADT, go to the Package Explorer, and open the folder called **bin**.
2. Now install BlueStacks (http://www.bluestacks.com/), a free Android emulator for Windows/Macs.
3. Go back to ADT and copy the .apk file in the **bin** folder to your desktop.
4. Open BlueStacks and install the .apk file and it should work! :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run your application from the emulator? You need to click the 'play' button to get it to run on your emulator and then it should execute on the emulator itself.

[image]

Once you do that you should be able to view it in the app drawer of the emulator itself, like so:

[image]

Comment: I have done exactly what you say to do but it won't show up in the emulator.  I started with the latest version of android sdk but have since installed every other sdk and tried recreating this project under the 2.3 framework instead of the 4.  Still no luck.

Comment: Did you use the application? Like could you play around with the app itself?