# Android app not executed in avd

Tags: android, macos, sdk, android-virtual-device

I've installed the Android SDK in my OSX Mountain Lion, from the following url
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
where is only required to unzip the file to get the environment working fine.

It's true that it works, but when I try to execute in avd the emulator opens, but the app never appears.

I've tried with different devices and with different apps, and executing `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`. But is not working.

**EDIT:**

The console says:

```
[2012-12-25 22:47:00 - test] Android Launch!
[2012-12-25 22:47:00 - test] adb is running normally.
[2012-12-25 22:47:00 - test] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-12-25 22:47:00 - test] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2012-12-25 22:47:00 - test] Performing sync
[2012-12-25 22:47:00 - test] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'mobile_test_4.1'
[2012-12-25 22:47:00 - test] Uploading test.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-12-25 22:47:00 - test] Installing test.apk...
[2012-12-25 22:47:04 - test] Success!
[2012-12-25 22:47:04 - test] /test/bin/test.apk installed on device
[2012-12-25 22:47:04 - test] Done!
```

Comment: First, see if the app is installed in the emulator. You may be able to run it yourself (unlock the emulator, go to the application list, tap on the app). Second, what does the console log say?

Comment: No, the app is not installed, it doesn't appear. And I've edited the message with the log.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean "No Launcher activity found!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801371/what-does-it-mean-no-launcher-activity-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, yes, "No launcher activity found" is a good indication of the problem. See [What does it mean “No Launcher activity found!”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801371/what-does-it-mean-no-launcher-activity-found).