# The <activity> element must be a direct child of the <application> element

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-activity, metadata

I just wanted to launch my application, but it always fails and gives me this error. Before, it would just install the .apk file, but now it just fails to start at all. I just began and was following the Android Developing tutorial.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.myfirstapp"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <activity
                    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
                    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
                    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
                    <meta-data
                        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </meta-data>
                </activity>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have nested activity tags inside your Manifest, fix this issue and it should work.

Comment: Now it's telling me, "No Launcher activity found!".

Comment: You need to specify one activity as your launcher activity inside intent-filter. Follow the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801371/what-does-it-mean-no-launcher-activity-found)

Answer (score 2):

YES - for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" /> 

  <application 
      android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <!-- Boot window -->
    <activity 
        android:name=".ServicesDemo" android:label="@string/app_name">        
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />           
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />     
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <!-- Second window -->
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:parentActivityName=".ServicesDemo" />       
    <!-- Second window -->
    <activity android:name=".MyWall" android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:parentActivityName=".ServicesDemo" />    
    <!-- Second window -->
    <activity android:name=".MyRotations" android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:parentActivityName=".ServicesDemo" />
    <!-- Second window -->
    <activity android:name=".MySetting" android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:parentActivityName=".ServicesDemo" />

    <receiver 
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".IntentReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />            
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />            
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />            
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>  

    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyNewpic" />

  </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't *nest* `Activities` in other `Activities`. This is how it should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </meta-data>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Do read the Android docs for the [AndroidManifest.xml file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Comment: It's telling me, "No Launcher activity found!".

Comment: @user2345325: Which among the two Activities should be the first one? And not their ordering. Which one should run first when your app icon is clicked?