# runtime-error.When receive Intent

Tags: android, runtime-error

1. this is MainActivity

   ```
   package com.example.createviews;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   //ประกาศตัวแปร
   EditText inputname;
   EditText inputemail;
   Button log_in;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.linear_layout);
       // view matching
       inputname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
       inputemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
       Button log_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.log_in);
       // button event
       log_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
               //starting a new intent
               Intent receiveData  =   new         Intent(getApplicationContext(),ReceiveDataActivity.class);
               //sent data to otheractivity
               receiveData.putExtra("name", inputname.getText().toString());
               receiveData.putExtra("email",inputemail.getText().toString());

               startActivity(receiveData);
           }

       });
   }
   }
   ```

   2.this ReceiveActivity
       package com.example.createviews;

   ```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class ReceiveDataActivity extends Activity {
   TextView txtname;
   TextView txtemail;
   Button close;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       //หน้าที่จะให้โชว์
       setContentView(R.layout.receivedata_layout);
       //view matching
        txtname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        txtemail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
        close = (Button)findViewById(R.id.close);
        //รับค่า intent
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
        String email = i.getStringExtra("email");

        //นำค่าที่รับมาแสดง
        txtname.setText(name);
        txtemail.setText(email);

        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   //Closing SecondScreen Activity
                   finish();
               }
           });
   }
   ```

   }

   This is my logcat output ::
   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.createviews/com.example.createviews.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at com.example.createviews.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)

   08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  ... 11 more

Comment: mabye a little bit more details about Your problem will help us. Also post the logcat please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting

```
Intent receiveData  =   new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ReceiveDataActivity.class);
```

try to write it as

```
Intent receiveData  =   new Intent(MainActivity.this,ReceiveDataActivity.class);
```

EDIT after logcat input:

The problem is here:

```
08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
08-17 16:51:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(704): at com.example.createviews.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
```

check you linear_layout.xml and check if the widget type for your inputemail. You must have specified it as TextView. Change it to EditText.

Comment: Brother,i have a second problem when I run application with emulator
it say " No Launcher activity found " and "The launch will only sync the application package on the device!"

Comment: this is my androidManifest


    package="com.example.createviews"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="ReceiveDataActivity"></activity>
    </application>

Comment: That was because you were possibly missing <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> in your manifest.xml file. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4801401/1952459) for example.

Answer (score 0):

So, without seeing logcat output it is hard to say, and also my magic ball still is black(is it damaged?). What I´ve seen is that Your code is really simple, so the possible issue could be that You don´t have registered Your Activity in Your manifest.xml . Open Your Manifest.xml and select the Tab "Application". Scroll down, and check if this activity is listed left. If not, selecte "Add"-->"Activity"-->then a second screen is open on the right. Choose "Browse" and wait until this Activity is listed. Choose this and press ok, then save. Also, there is a second issue in Your code from Your Main Activity. You referred Your log button the wrong way:

```
   Button log_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.log_in);
```

But You declared the button above, so just do this:

```
   log_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.log_in);
```

### EDIT

this new error seems that You have some wrong initializations. Look here:

```
   android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

To get rid of this, please post Your layout xml. It seems that Your "inputname" or "inputemail" EditText is really a TextView inside Your xml layout

Comment: Thank you i just insert logcat error you can see it on the top