# new to android, not able to run project from github on phone

Tags: java, android

I tried to import this project form github into eclipse then I right clicked on the project which is called 'main' - chose "run as" - android application, yet the application did not automatically run on my phone, rather nothing happened. Here is what my console states:

> 2013-11-02 14:25:11 - main] ------------------------------ [2013-11-02
>   14:25:11 - main] Android Launch! [2013-11-02 14:25:11 - main] adb is
>   running normally. [2013-11-02 14:25:11 - main] No Launcher activity
>   found! [2013-11-02 14:25:11 - main] The launch will only sync the
>   application package on the device! [2013-11-02 14:25:11 - main]
>   Performing sync [2013-11-02 14:25:11 - main] Automatic Target Mode:
>   using device '0149B3A10400A004' [2013-11-02 14:25:12 - main]
>   Application already deployed. No need to reinstall. [2013-11-02
>   14:25:12 - main] /main/bin/main.apk installed on device [2013-11-02
>   14:25:12 - main] Done!

I looked for some app called main, but didnt find it. but still, it should have launched automatically..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean "No Launcher activity found!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801371/what-does-it-mean-no-launcher-activity-found)

Comment: can you give a link to the project? Is it a widget or something?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your [manifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) doesn't declare an Activity as launcher Activity. You need to specify an Activity and insert an Intent-Filter in its declaration in the manifest.xml like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="[package-name].[activity-name]"
        android:label="[app_name]" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```