# No launcher activity found in eclipse java android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, manifest, launcher

I'm getting something that looks like this:

"No Launcher activity found!
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!"

I'm not sure how to fix this. My AndroidManifest looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the launcher is defined by the manifest.  I think it's defined by the Eclipse environment.  Check your Run Configurations and see where it's trying to launch the thing.

Comment: This question has been answered several times. For example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4801401/3571822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the activity to your manifest. For example, if your initial activity is called MainActivity:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity"
        android:label="Main Activity!" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Edit: The above shows an activity that is also being used as a launcher. Here is an example of a regular activity also being added to the manifest.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity"
        android:label="Main Activity!" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.helloworld.SecondActivity"
        android:label="My second activity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks! So do I have to add that to the XML file every time?

Comment: Yes, each activity that you create must be added to AndroidManifest.xml. (Although, if you are adding the activity through eclipse, it should handle this automatically...) In this case, you are setting the activity to be the initial activity - any other activities must be added as well, although they are slightly different. I'll add the format for a regular activity into my answer.

Comment: Ah I see thank you very much! Now I'm having a problem where it's building onto the Android device, except it opens up and then quits out after 5 seconds. It displays a message saying: "Unfortunately, HelloWorld has stopped."

Comment: Sounds like you have an error elsewhere as well. Try looking at the LogCat where it crashes and it should give you some clues as to what the issue is.

Comment: Okay I checked and it looks something like this:

07-01 13:02:54.762: E/SELinux(21045): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
07-01 13:02:54.762: D/dalvikvm(21045): Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-01 13:02:54.912: D/AndroidRuntime(21045): Shutting down VM
07-01 13:02:54.912: W/dalvikvm(21045): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411b4ac8)
07-01 13:02:54.912: E/AndroidRuntime(21045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Answer (score 0):

You should add your acivities to the manifest file.

For Example:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
  <activity
        android:name="<Package><ClassName>"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
   </activity>

</applicaion>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create Android Project in Eclipse it automatically generates a class called `MainActivity` which extends activity and generates `Manifest` file for you with a default entry of your `MainActivity`. Whenever you create a new class that extends `Activity` then you have to manually enter your activity in your manifest. You can change your your intent filter any time and you can set it to any activity and that activity will be your launcher activity of the app. This is a default Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```