# Android launcher activity not found

Tags: android-launcher

I am an Android newbie,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.exaggmple.sadgh"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



</application>

</manifest>
```

thıs ıs my manıfest.xml, but ı stıll get the error lıke no launcher :( , please help. thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801371/what-does-it-mean-no-launcher-activity-found

Comment: Thanks but ıt dıdnt work wıth that solutıon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean "No Launcher activity found!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801371/what-does-it-mean-no-launcher-activity-found)