# one signal script androidmanifest xml Unable to start activity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I trying to publish from unity to android, but theses message display on the console.

**UnityException**: Unable to start activity!
No activity in the manifest with action MAIN and category LAUNCHER. Try launching the application manually on the device.

Here my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.onesignal.onesignalsdk"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     <application>
     </application> </manifest>
```

What do i need to do? The manifest is located on Plugins/Android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean "No Launcher activity found!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801371/what-does-it-mean-no-launcher-activity-found)

Comment: Activity tag seems to be missing and activities must be placed inside application tag not like the above

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare an activity with that action. Like:

```
<activity android:name=".BurgersActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: i have 2 manifest, this first is automatic generated by onesignal sdk. Android/Plugin/OneSignalConfig

and this other manifest is to enable location service. Android/Plugin

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.onesignal.onesignalsdk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    
    <application>
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: No activity in the manifest with action MAIN and category LAUNCHER.